# Auto Resolve Nuget Package Version Conflicts C#

Tags: c#, git, nuget

We have a few packages that are consumed across our solutions, when one package gets updated a few times it's often the case that some pull requests will end up with a load of conflicting versions of this package.

These are really easy to resolve by hand, just go through them and select the latest version.

However, I feel like there should be an easy way to automatically resolve specifically this kind of merge conflict to just select the highest package number.

Is there a tool that already does this?